# Unexpected frozen matplotlib figure window every 2nd time I run my program

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, scipy, spyder

My program is a simulation of the solar system. I'm using matplotlib to animate it, then when the animation figure is closed, create and show a graph using data from the simulation. Using Spyder3.3.3, everything works as intended the first time I run the code, but if I try to run the program a second time, a blank, unresponsive window pops up before either the animation or the graph parts of the code are executed. I have to get windows to force close that window, then the program crashes without any error messages.

I thought the problem might be this code that I recently added:

```
def onclose(evt):
        print("\n" + "Animation closed")
        fileout = open("SolarSystem total energy list.txt", "w")
        fileout.writelines(self.energy_str)
        graph_fig, graph_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 9))
        t_len = len(self.energy)
        y = np.around(np.divide(np.array(self.energy), 1e35), 12)
        x = np.linspace(0.0, self.timestep_hours*t_len, t_len)
        graph_ax.plot(x, y)
        graph_ax.set(xlabel="time(hours)", ylabel="total system energy (J [x10^35])")
        plt.show(block=False)
self.anim_fig.canvas.mpl_connect("close_event", onclose)
```

However, when I remove this, the same exact error occurs. In fact, on every second run, the code seems to be getting stuck in *this* block of code (which used to run perfectly every time):

```
while True:
    self.num_asteroids = int(input("Number of random asteroids (between 0 and 100): "))
    if self.num_asteroids >=0 and self.num_asteroids <=100 and isinstance(self.num_asteroids, int) == True :
        break
if self.num_asteroids != 0:
    for i in range(self.num_asteroids):
        while True:
            appearancetime = float(input("Time of appearance of random asteroid " + str(i+1) +  " in hours: "))
            if appearancetime >=0 and appearancetime <self.duration_hours:
                    self.asteroidlist.append(appearancetime)
                break
```

In the spyder ipython console "Number of random asteroids (between 0 and 100):" input prompt appears but I am unable to type. So it seems to be getting stuck there but I've no idea why a `matplotlib` window would pop up since only after that in the code do I have my `FuncAnimation()` and `plt.show()` lines.

Here's my animation code:

```
    for i in range(self.num_planets):
        self.patches.append(plt.Circle(self.planetlist[i].initial_position*1e-9, radiuslist[i], color=colourlist[i], animated=True))
    for i in range(self.asteroidlist.count(0.0)):
        self.patches.append(plt.Circle(tuple(self.bodylist[self.num_planets:][i].initial_position*1e-9), random.uniform(0.5, 1), color="#686868", animated=True))
    if simulation_type.upper() == "MARSSAT" or simulation_type.upper() == "MARS_SAT" or simulation_type.upper() == "JUPITERSAT" or simulation_type.upper() == "JUPITER_SAT":
        self.patches.append(plt.Circle(tuple(self.bodylist[-1].initial_position*1e-9), 0.5, colour="#37FF30", animated=True))
    for i in range(self.num_bodies):
        self.anim_ax.add_patch(self.patches[i])

    self.animation = FuncAnimation(self.anim_fig, self.update, init_func=self.anim_init, frames=self.total_frames, repeat=False, interval=self.interval, blit=True)
```

I have spyder set to use qt5 if that helps.

Comment: It looks to me like an indentation error, but maybe your post is just improperly formatted?

Comment: @Reedinationer The second bit of code? It was improperly formatted. Fixed, thanks.